# Problema ao usar CODEIGNITER em servidor Nginx

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, amazon-aws, php-fpm

Meu site estava hospedado na UOLHOST e funcionava perfeitamente com o seguinte .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?r=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Estou migrando para uma EC2 na Amazon e vou utilizar Nginx como servidor web em conjunto com o PHP-FPM.

Quem fez o site, disse que administração dele utilizava CODEIGNITER.

Alterei as configurações do config.php dentro de /application/config e apenas o website funciona, sua administração, não.

Eu tentei isso:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/meudominio.com.br;
    index index.php;
    server_name meudominio.com.br www.meudominio.com.br;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/meudominio.com.br.access;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/meudominio.com.br.error error;
    location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?r=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location /controle {
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
    }
    }
```

A pasta "CONTROLE" é onde fica a administração do website.

Alternativamente, eu criei um outro bloco e um sub-domínio apontando para a pasta controle. Conforme abaixo:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/meudominio.com.br/controle;
    index index.php;
    server_name adm.meudominio.com.br;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/meudominio.com.br.access;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/meudominio.com.br.error error;
    location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?r=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
    }
```

Acessando a administração do website pela url adm.meudominio.com.br eu consigo entrar e visualizar todos os itens administráveis do website.

No entanto, quando carrego imagens para o servidor, o caminho delas é modificado, conforme o root que eu setei para o sub-domínio.

> /usr/share/nginx/html/meudominio.com.br/controle

Quando na verdade eu preciso que as imagens sejam enviadas com base no root  "/usr/share/nginx/html/meudominio.com.br"

O que está acontecendo?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema incluindo as linhas a seguir

```
location /controle {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /controle/index.php?$args;
}
```

logo acima de:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
```

Com isso, o sistema utilizando CODEIGNITER se comportou no APACHE usando o .hataccess informado no início da publicação.

Answer (score -2):

Basta adicionar dentro do nginx.conf

server{

location / {
#try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
}